# Zend Framework. Modular structure

Tags: zend-framework

Doing modular directory structure. Ie I want the structure was as follows:

```
application
  modules
       default
           controllers
           models
           views 

       my
           controllers
           models
           views
```

The index controller works off (default / controller / IndexController.php).
But when I turn to the controller located in the directory my - displaying the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' 
>    with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in 
>   /home/webhouse/public_html/metr/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:248

The same error appears when I try to apply the model of the controller:

> Warning: include_once(IndexModel.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

**I added in application.ini:**

```
; Front Controller
 resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
 resources.modules = ""
```

What I still need to register in the file application.ini, so it works for me?)

Comment: What is the code of your /my/controller/IndexController.php ?

Answer (score 1):

Try naming you controller:

class My_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {}